# react-native buttons padding/margin top don't work

Tags: react-native, expo

I am tryin g to make the buttons login and register have top spacing from the logo above them but no css attributes work so far

I tried padding top/margin top and top but all don't work and margin left doesn't work also

here's the expo snack link:
https://snack.expo.io/@mai95/intelligent-tortillas

```
<Button title="Login" style={{top:300}} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details")} >
     <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOG IN</Text>
   </Button>  
   <Button title="Register"style={{top:300,marginLeft:50}}  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details")} >
     <Text style={styles.loginText2}>Register</Text>
   </Button>
```

any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles prop is not available on the `<Button />` component. You should consider wrapping the buttons in a div like so:

```
   <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 100 }}>
        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 25 }}>
          <Button title="Login" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}>
            <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOG IN</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 25 }}>
          <Button
            title="Register"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}>
            <Text style={styles.loginText2}>Register</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

MarginTop should be in a container `<View/>`

Here is the snippet working with marginTop:

```js
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', marginTop: 30}}>
    <Button title="Login" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details")} >
     <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOG IN</Text>
   </Button>  
   <Button title="Register"  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details")} >
     <Text style={styles.loginText2}>Register</Text>
   </Button>
</View>
```